# Is it possible to activate the reading mode of Firefox or Chrome with Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to automate some online media news downloads. Since not all web pages follow the DOM of their structure, I open web pages with Chrome or Firefox and take screenshots and then send them to an OCR of my own development. The problem is that it brings a lot of junk information from the advertising and the page. For this reason, I thought about making selenium open the browser's reading view and extract much cleaner information.

Comment: I am doing my development in Python 3

Comment: provide some code or images to illustrate your problem for people to better understand and be able to help you

Answer (score 0):

The readability library that Mozilla uses in Firefox is open source and available here:  https://github.com/mozilla/readability

You can fetch the web contents in selenium and pass out all through this process to get the text output without needing an OCR step at all.